# PHP is not creating Text File when executed using a Cron

Tags: php, cron

I have created a php file that fetches some data from a mysql database and save it in a text file. I am using Windows 7 and Xampp. I have created a batch file and entered the following code so that it can be executed at regular intervals.

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fetch.php
```

I am using Z-Cron for running the task at regular intervals. Now the problem is that whenever the batch file is executed through this software or Windows Task Scheduler, no text file is created and if I run the batch file manually the text file is created without any problems.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Which account is the the scheduled task run? Does it have the appropriate permission?

Comment: What is the "Start in" Directory set to when you run from the Windows Task Manager?

Comment: This may be permission problem.

Comment: Could you check the permission of the user account that Z-Cron runs under.

Answer (score 0):

set the full absolute path for the created file.

Comment: @Daniel: The file is running with an administrator account

@Mark: I don't know how to set the Start in Directory